# Nexus 9 stuck on setup screen because of Wi-Fi?

Tags: wi-fi

I performed a factory reset on my rooted Nexus 9, and when I tried to start anew, I can't connect to any Wi-Fi network (with the exception of my phone hotspot), and I'm stuck here.  Since I factory reset, I lost access to developer options and I can't USB debug.

I have tried wiping the cache, factory resetting, and wiping all data, but nothing seems to get the Wi-Fi working (The Wi-Fi works fine on my computer and the family iPad).  It's always saving the network, but never actually connecting to it.  In the end, the Nexus 9 tells me "Avoided Poor Internet Connection" when in reality, the internet connection is excellent.

Is there anything that I can do to fix this, just in case Best Buy (where I purchased my tablet) says that my warranty is voided?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Reflash? Although it's probably not the "good" solution, try doing it. Also, in the eu, if you didn't destroy the tablet because you had root, you're still covered

Comment: So how would I reflash my Nexus 9 if it doesn't even show up on USB?

Comment: use fastboot, you know

Comment: To reflash: Download stock ROM zip or tar.gz, and run flash-all.(bat/sh)